# TabLayout crashing after updating support library to 23.2.1

Tags: java, android, material-design

Everything was working fine until i updated my gradle file and now my tablayout is crashing due to error:

> Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:  Landroid/support/v7/widget/TintManager;
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.(TabLayout.java:1185)
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:656)
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:695)
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:386)
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:361)
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:645)
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:616)
>      at com.example.ScrollableTabsActivity.onCreate(ScrollableTabsActivity.java:307)
>      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
>      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.(TabLayout.java:1185) 
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:656) 
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:695) 
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:386) 
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:361) 
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:645) 
>      at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:616)

Here is my `gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+@aar'
compile 'com.github.hotchemi:stringpicker:0.0.2'
compile files('libs/devsmartlib.jar')
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile project(':lib')
}
```

Please help me where am wrong

Comment: is the buildToolsVersion the last version ??

Comment: no have updated it from 23.0.1 and even after rolling back am getting the same error

Comment: I am not sure but I think You have to change the compile in Your gradle to the current version: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

Comment: you should try with `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya How's r23.2.1 not stable?

Comment: All support libs must have the same version. 23.2.1 or 23.1.1 or whatever but you can't mix versions.

Comment: All support libraries must be same version.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

changing dependencies did the trick , just added com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0 and updated build tools version to 23.0.2

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
```

I dont know why some people marked my question as negative, anyways this might help someone

Comment: 23.2.0 is broken, use 23.2.1. http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 9):

All support libs must have the same version. 23.2.1 or 23.1.1 or whatever but you can't mix versions.

```
ext.supportLibVersion = "23.2.1"
// design includes recyclerview-v7 and appcompat-v7, which includes support-v4
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
```

Comment: upvoted for the comment that design includes appompat-v7

Comment: "All support libs must have the same version" is the key statement.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score -1):

You first create a new  activity but not empty activity and choose tabed activity ,then do as I did..

step 1 : create three fragment activity first delete everything from each fragment activity and write this code to each activity

```
package com.yourpakagename.tabedactivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class layout1 extends Fragment {
public layout1() {
// Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout12, container, false);
//changes in each activity-->R.layout.fragment_layout_name<----
}
}
```

step 2 : and finally in your tabbed activity we dont need this two functions

```
  public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}


public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
    return rootView;
}
}
```

step 3: and finally change your sectionpageradapter function with this code thats it -->

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    //delete  return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            return new layout1();
        case 1:
            return new layout2();
        case 2:
            return new layout3();
        default:
            return  new layout1();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "SECTION 1";
        case 1:
            return "SECTION 2";
        case 2:
            return "SECTION 3";
    }
    return null;
 }
 }
```